# Misaligned month label in TikZ calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, calendar

I'm putting together a multi-month calendar in Ti*k*Z and am seeing some awkward and undesired alignment in the month labels despite using the `month label above centered` style.  In particular, the month label appears to be centered only over the first **six** columns, rather than over all **seven:**

[image: Observed vs Desired alignments of month label]

I've reproduced my code below in a minimal context.  **Two questions:** What's going on here, and how can I correct this alignment?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes}

\makeatletter%
\tikzstyle{week list sunday}=[
        % Note that we cannot extend from week list,
        % the execute before day scope is cumulative
        execute before day scope={%
               \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}{
               % On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
                   \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%
                   \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
               }}{}%
        },
        execute at begin day scope={%
            % Because for TikZ Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6,
            % we can't directly use \pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
            % but instead we define \c@pgf@counta (basically) as:
            % (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday + 1) % 7
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
            \ifnum\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday=6
                \c@pgf@counta=0
            \else
                \c@pgf@counta=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday
                \advance\c@pgf@counta by 1
            \fi
            \pgf@x=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x
            % Shift to the right position for the day.
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
        },
        execute after day scope={
            % Week is done, shift to the next line.
            \ifdate{Saturday}{
                % But not if it's already the last day of the month.
                \ifdate{end of month=1}{}{
                    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
                    \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
                }%
            }{}%
        },
        % This should be defined, glancing from the source code.
        tikz@lib@cal@width=7
    ]

\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{every calendar}=[week list sunday,
    month label above centered,
    month text=\textbf{\%mt~\%y-},
    day xshift = 0.5cm,
    day letter headings]
\tikzstyle{every day}=[anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/S,1/M,2/T,3/W,4/T,5/F,6/S} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
      }
    }{}%
  }%
]

\makeatother%

% ==================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar (K) [dates=2013-01-01 to 2013-03-last]
    if (weekend) [black!40];
\draw[black](K-2013-01-21) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-02-13) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-10) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-31) circle (0.6em);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Misaligned month label in TikZ calendar]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can increase the value for `tikz@lib@cal@width` for example, to `7.8`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes}

\makeatletter%
\tikzstyle{week list sunday}=[
        % Note that we cannot extend from week list,
        % the execute before day scope is cumulative
        execute before day scope={%
               \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}{
               % On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
                   \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%
                   \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
               }}{}%
        },
        execute at begin day scope={%
            % Because for TikZ Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6,
            % we can't directly use \pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
            % but instead we define \c@pgf@counta (basically) as:
            % (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday + 1) % 7
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
            \ifnum\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday=6
                \c@pgf@counta=0
            \else
                \c@pgf@counta=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday
                \advance\c@pgf@counta by 1
            \fi
            \pgf@x=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x
            % Shift to the right position for the day.
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
        },
        execute after day scope={
            % Week is done, shift to the next line.
            \ifdate{Saturday}{
                % But not if it's already the last day of the month.
                \ifdate{end of month=1}{}{
                    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
                    \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
                }%
            }{}%
        },
        % This should be defined, glancing from the source code.
        tikz@lib@cal@width=7.8
    ]

\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{every calendar}=[week list sunday,
    month label above centered,
    month text=\textbf{\%mt~\%y-},
    day xshift = 0.5cm,
    day letter headings]
\tikzstyle{every day}=[anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/S,1/M,2/T,3/W,4/T,5/F,6/S} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
      }
    }{}%
  }%
]

\makeatother%

% ==================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar (K) [dates=2013-01-01 to 2013-03-last]
    if (weekend) [black!40];
\draw[black](K-2013-01-21) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-02-13) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-10) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-31) circle (0.6em);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty good, but why `7.8`, specifically?  Is `tikz@lib@cal@width` effectively a multiple of `day xshift`?  If so, why doesn't `7` work in this example?  I'm trying to understand the root cause of the problem...

Comment: After some experimentation, it seems the value which "correctly" centers the label in this example is `7.9`, but I still don't have any additional insight into what that value actually represents and why `7` doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @TimParenti I really don't know; I've never used the `calendar` library, so I am not familiar with how it works; I found the "dirty fix" by detecting which part of your code had to do with the horizontal alignment of the month label and that's how `tikz@lib@cal@width` appeared. The value `7.8` was found by trial/error.

Comment: I suppose a "dirty fix" is better than no fix at all.  Still leaves me with a bad taste, but hey... at least it works.  I'm going to hold off on accepting this for another day or so in case anyone else can offer a more insightful solution.  _(But congrats on 100k!)_

Comment: @TimParenti sure, I would also like to know if someone offers a "proper" calculation ("manual" guessing are by no means my favorite either). Thanks for the congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in pgf. You use the `month label above centered` key to place the month name above the days, which is defined in the file `tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex` as

```
\tikzset{month label above centered/.style={%
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      {
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgf@xb=\tikz@lib@cal@width\pgf@xa%
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xb=.5\pgf@xb%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%
        \pgftransformxshift{-1.5ex}%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{1.25\pgf@y}
        \tikzmonthcode%
      }
    }{}},
  every month/.append style={anchor=base}
}}
```

Apparenty, there is an extra `\pgftransformxshift{-1.5ex}`, which is responsible for the misalignment. If you replace `month label above centered` in your code with the above definition but with `\pgftransformxshift{-1.5ex}` removed, you will get the correct alignment. Here is your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes}

\makeatletter%
\tikzstyle{week list sunday}=[
        % Note that we cannot extend from week list,
        % the execute before day scope is cumulative
        execute before day scope={%
               \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}{
               % On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
                   \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%
                   \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
               }}{}%
        },
        execute at begin day scope={%
            % Because for TikZ Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6,
            % we can't directly use \pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
            % but instead we define \c@pgf@counta (basically) as:
            % (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday + 1) % 7
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
            \ifnum\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday=6
                \c@pgf@counta=0
            \else
                \c@pgf@counta=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday
                \advance\c@pgf@counta by 1
            \fi
            \pgf@x=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x
            % Shift to the right position for the day.
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
        },
        execute after day scope={
            % Week is done, shift to the next line.
            \ifdate{Saturday}{
                % But not if it's already the last day of the month.
                \ifdate{end of month=1}{}{
                    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
                    \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}
                }%
            }{}%
        },
        % This should be defined, glancing from the source code.
        tikz@lib@cal@width=7
    ]

\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{every calendar}=[week list sunday,
% Replace this:
%    month label above centered
% With this modified extract from 'tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex':
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      {
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgf@xb=\tikz@lib@cal@width\pgf@xa%
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xb=.5\pgf@xb%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%
%        \pgftransformxshift{-1.5ex}% Removed misalignment
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{1.25\pgf@y}
        \tikzmonthcode%
      }
    }{}},
  every month/.append style={anchor=base}
% End of replacement text. Comma follows.
    ,
    month text=\textbf{\%mt~\%y-},
    day xshift = 0.5cm,
    day letter headings]
\tikzstyle{every day}=[anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/S,1/M,2/T,3/W,4/T,5/F,6/S} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
      }
    }{}%
  }%
]

\makeatother%

% ==================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar (K) [dates=2013-01-01 to 2013-03-last]
    if (weekend) [black!40];
\draw[black](K-2013-01-21) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-02-13) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-10) circle (0.6em);
\draw[black](K-2013-03-31) circle (0.6em);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```